# Oracle Regexp_Substr or Regexp_Replace query,not getting all the cases satisfied

Tags: sql, oracle

I am on Oracle 12c R1
I want to extract the first two part of the string and the last one which has X

```
  Input : 'AB12,AB23,AB50,AB71X,AB43,AB98X,AB11'
    Expected Output :  AB12,AB23,AB98
```

Tried the below,

```
  SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('AB12,AB23,AB50,AB71X,AB43,AB98X,AB11','(.{9}).*(,.{4})X(.+$)?','\1\2) col1 FROM dual;
```

But could not get the X part correctly for below string

```
  'AB12X,AB23X,AB50X,AB71,AB43'   Expected Output => AB12,AB23,AB50
                                  Output => AB12X,AB2,AB50

  'AB12,AB23X'                    Expected Output => AB12,AB23
                                  Output => AB12,AB23X
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @gary-w after spending sometime and trial and error I got this *REGEXP_REPLACE('string',(.{4})?X?(,?.{4})?.?(.*(,.{4})X)?(.+$)?','\1\2\4)* can it be more simplied

Answer (score 2):

No need for regex. You can use `instr` with th_appearance = -1 to start from the end

```
  with t as (select 'AB12,AB23,AB50,AB71X,AB43,AB98X,AB11' as input from dual)
  select 
  substr(input,1, instr(input,',', 1)-1) as firstPart,
  substr(input,instr(input,',', 1)+1, instr(input,',', 1, 1)-1) as secondPart,
  substr(substr(input,1, instr(input,'X,', -1)-1), instr(substr(input,1, instr(input,'X,', -1)), ',', -1)+1) as thirdPart
  from t;
```

Returns:

```
 AB12   AB23    AB98
```

Or concatenated:

```
 with t as (select 'AB12,AB23,AB50,AB71X,AB43,AB98X,AB11' as input from dual)
  select 
  substr(input,1, instr(input,',', 1)-1) || ',' ||
  substr(input,instr(input,',', 1)+1, instr(input,',', 1, 1)-1)  || ',' ||
  substr(substr(input,1, instr(input,'X,', -1)-1), instr(substr(input,1, instr(input,'X,', -1)), ',', -1)+1) as output
  from t;
```

Returns:

```
AB12,AB23,AB98
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! and your time.Appreciate

Answer (score 1):

This query can help:

```
select listagg(c1, ',') within group (order by null) from
 (select c1, lvl, rn, max(rn) over (partition by null) rn2 from 
   (select c1, lvl, case when c1 like '%X' then rownum end rn from 
      (select regexp_substr('AB12,AB23,AB50,AB71X,AB43,AB98X,AB11','[^,]+', 1, level) c1, level lvl from dual
      connect by regexp_substr('AB12,AB23,AB50,AB71X,AB43,AB98X,AB11', '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null)
    ) t
  )
where lvl in (1,2)
   or rn2 = rn
order by lvl asc;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. Appreciate your help.Looks good! Just curious if it can be achieved in one select

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
select regexp_replace('AB12,AB23,AB50,AB71X,AB43,AB98X,AB11', '^(.{4},.{4}),.*,(.{4})X.*$', '\1,\2')
from dual;
```